# How do I exclude a specific extension from recursive file copying?

Tags: command-line, cp

I want to copy all of the files and subdirs except the data file which named *.data to a destination dir.

```
 [ichen@ui01 sub_test]$ ls
a.cxx  a.data  subdir
[ichen@ui01 sub_test]$ ls subdir/
sub_a.cxx  sub_a.data
```

You can see, there are 2 data files in the outside dir and subdir respectively.
I used this command:

```
[ichen@ui01 sub_test]$ cp -r !(*.data) ../destination_dir/
```

aimed to copy all of the files except the *.data to the destination, but it's not work in the subdir:

```
  [ichen@ui01 destination_dir]$ ls
a.cxx  subdir
[ichen@ui01 destination_dir]$ ls subdir/
sub_a.cxx  sub_a.data
```

You can see above that this command just work on the first dir, how can I make it works in all of the subdirs?

Comment: I will rewrite my answer for you.  Sorry about that. :)

Comment: @Terrance never mind.

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: @Terrance not yet. If I figured out, I will tell you( :

Comment: Never mind.  Mine didn't work either.  Sorry. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't specify in your question if it is a requirement to preserve the directory structure in the copy or if you just need a copy of the files. To simply copy all the files not named *.data you could use this:

```
find . -type f ! -name '*.data' | xargs cp -t ../destination_dir/
```

On the other hand if you want to preserve the directory structure you could use something like this:

```
for file in `find . ! -name '*.txt' | sed 's/^.\///'`; do if [ -d "./$file" ]; then mkdir -p "../destination_dir/$file"; else cp "./$file" "../destination_dir/$file"; fi; done
```

Not sure if there is a simpler way to do this but this command does the following:

Find all files and folders in the current directory or it's subfolders not matching *.data then for each:

Test if the file is a directory if it is make a matching directory under destination dir, or if it is a file it copies it to the destination instead.

Edit: Adding shell script version:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Disable shell glob expansion within the script
# Required to stop bash from expndinging the glob in $1
set -f

for file in `find . ! -name $1 | sed 's/^.\///'`
  do if [ -d "./$file" ]; then
    mkdir -p "$2/$file"
  else
    cp "./$file" "$2/$file"
fi
done
```

Comment: Thank you! Your method perfectly settled my problem, however, are you interested of writing this as a "cp_exception.sh" file and make "*.data" as the parameter of this shell script? We may execute this script like: "sh cp_exception.sh * .data" . It's could be very useful.

Comment: In fact, I tried about this, but still can not achieve. If write as a shell script, there must be two basically parameters: the name(s) of file(s) which we don't wanna to copy and the path of destination dir.

Comment: I added a shell script form note the use of set -f within this script, this prevents bash from expanding the shell glob (*) while expanding the $1 variable. Do remember to use the single quotes when calling the script however so that you are actually passing the pattern and not a filename expansion as the input to the script.

Comment: You should not do ``for f in `find …`; do …``. That will easily break with spaces and other special characters. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs